# Example of a certain locally univalent function

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I'm looking for an example of a non-quadratic analytic function $f\colon \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ (a power series with infinite radius of convergence) that has the following three properties:

1. $f(0)=0$.
2. $f'(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}$.
3. $f''(x)\ne 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{C}$.

I'm embarrassed, I can't find one! nor prove that such a function exists.

Edit notes: Notice the following:

- $f$ will not be locally univalent because $f'(x)=0$ for some $x\in \mathbb{R}$.
- $f'$ is required to be locally univalent because $f''(x)\ne 0$ everywhere in $\mathbb{C}$.
- the restriction of $f'$ to $\mathbb{R}$ must be either increasing or  decreasing by (3) and (2).
- if $f''$ is constant, then $f$ is quadratic.
- $f$ cannot be polynomial of degree greater than two because of (3).
- from the Big Picard Theorem in the non-constant $f''$ case $f''$ attains all the complex values with the exception of zero (as in $e^x$).

In summary my hunch is that any example will be a composition involving $e^x$.

Comment: By "locally univalent," you meant you want $f`$ to also be non-zero everywhere?

Comment: I mean that $f'$ is locally univalent. That is $f''$ is non-zero everywhere. Of course, $f'$ will have a zero, thus $f$ is not locally univalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paulo Monteiro who is not a member here and who is at FGV in Rio (where Chile is likely to win the world cup this year) sent me an example:

Let $f''(x) = e^{x^2}$. Obviously, $f''(x)\ne 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{C}$. In this case:
$$
f'(x)= \sum_{n} \frac{x^{2n +1}}{(2n+1)n!}
$$
Notice that $f'(\pm \infty) = \pm \infty$, respectively. Thus, $f'(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}$. Finally, 
$$
f(x)= \sum_{n} \frac{x^{2n +2}}{(2n+2)(2n+1)n!}
$$
and $f(0)=0$.

Comment: You have a typo, it should be $$f''(x) = e^{x^2},$$ not $e^{2x}$. And at the bottom, you have the series of $f$, not of $f''$.

Comment: Yep  I changed it.